# How to make multiple forms navigate inside a Container?

Tags: c#, winforms

Finally I achieved to make a container to open 1 form but then I noticed that if I go to other forms, the container simply disappear (maybe looses inheritance).

The code that is working for opening a single form inside a container is:

```
LandingForm myForm = new LandingForm();
myForm.TopLevel = false;
myForm.AutoScroll = true;
panel1.Controls.Add(myForm);
myForm.Show();
```

Can someone help me how to make all my forms navigate inside my container?

Thank you

Comment: Why not using MDI forms?

Comment: I struggled with that :(
I wanna do something by myself so I can understand. Unfortunately I couldn't be able to make an MDI Form successfully

Comment: Well, obviously the way you are trying to do this is wrong. Check out these two articles on MDI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-mdi-parent-forms
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-mdi-child-forms

Comment: I've seen them already. Well.. I guess I have to push harder.

Comment: I created the Parent MDI Form. Then i look into the child creation tutorial and it seems similar? Makes no sense to me at all. And their logic is to display child forms when clicking on the Menu. I don't want that

Comment: Forget the tutorial about child windows, Just do this: `(new Form2() { MdiParent = this }).Show();`

Comment: Alright but I still have to create an MDI Parent right?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little sick and making a lot of confusion... maybe this is all easy lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Making a MDI WinForm application**

1. Create an `ParentForm` and a `ChildForm`
2. Replace the code of the `ParentForm` with this example:

   ```
   public ParentForm()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       IsMdiContainer = true;
   }

   private void ParentForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       new ChildForm {MdiParent = this}.Show();
   }
   ```

[image: MDI Form]

**Open Multiple forms in one container**

1. Create an `ParentForm` and a `ChildForm`
2. Replace the code of the `ParentForm` with this example:

   ```
   public ParentForm()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       DoubleClick += ParentForm_DoubleClick;
   }

   private void ParentForm_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
   {
       var child = new ChildForm
       {
           TopLevel = false,
           AutoScroll = true
       };
       child.Location = new Point(
           MousePosition.X - Location.X - child.Size.Width/2,
           MousePosition.Y - Location.Y - child.Size.Height/2);
       child.Click += Child_OnClick;
       child.Closing += Child_OnClosing;
       Controls.Add(child);
       Controls.SetChildIndex(child, 0);
       child.Show();
       child.Activate();
   }

   private void Child_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs cancelEventArgs)
   {
       ((ChildForm)sender).Click -= Child_OnClick;
       ((ChildForm)sender).Closing -= Child_OnClosing;
       Controls.Remove((ChildForm)sender);
   }

   private void Child_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
   {
       Controls.SetChildIndex((ChildForm)sender, 0);
       ((ChildForm)sender).Activate();
   }
   ```

Now you can double click on an empty area to add a new form, and you can also switch between them by clicking on the child form's surface.

[image: Form as Control Example]

Comment: My application is based on a MasterForm which shares an UI Header and the other forms are based on it with other custom components.

I just want my MasterForm to be the parent container and the others childs in the same position/location.

Comment: If you have a base form (instead of a parent form), you have two option. 1. Inherit other forms from the parent form and just show them. 2. Better, design all your forms as "Custom Control"s and show them in the main form. In other word, make your app single form, everything else is a control. Even the content of each page in your application

Comment: Update: Additional information: Form cannot be both an MDI child and MDI parent. I double checked isMdiContainer... and its true. The other Form is not mdicontainer

Comment: How to do the first solution? Not sure how to make that.
The second may give me a lot of work?

Comment: The main reason I wanna do this is because of the navigation.
When i go to other form, he opens another window and I wanna avoid that. If I have a parent form which makes a container to navigate all the forms inside. 

Did you get it what I said? Thanks